# Unable to deploy to server running Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a Spring application to server running Apache Tomcat. However, I get this error:

> SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: …
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RuralIvrs]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   …
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.(WsServerContainer.java:147)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           ... 10 more
>
> Jan 21, 2016 12:16:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployWAR … SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive
>   /home/ruralivrs/Ruralict/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/RuralIvrs.war
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RuralIvrs]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I was unable to find a solution after searching for several hours. Since I am quite new to this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are using `Spring Boot`, true? And you are trying to run a Tomcat 7, yes?

Comment: post complete exception message

Comment: I'm glad, it seems you've found a solution. You may share for future readers what exactly solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find similar problem in [this blog post](https://stevewall123.wordpress.com/2015/04/17/spring-boot-application-and-tomcat-error-a-child-container-failed-during-start/).

The solution is probably as simple as adding a `tomcat.version` property to your Maven project’s pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.67</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

The reason is explained inside Spring Boot documentation for [embedded-servlet-containers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-7).
Spring Boot defaults to `Tomcat 8`, so you need to tell Spring Boot that your target is `Tomcat 7`.

Comment: Thanks! I have to figure out how to include this in Gradle.

Comment: In Gradle it would be: `ext['tomcat.version'] = '7.0.67'`

Comment: I added: ext['tomcat.version'] = '7.0.42'   Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Error still the same? Are you using Spring Boot at all :)? Also please consider updating your question with the full stack trace from your exception.